# How to access a TextView inside of a DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a a text for my TextView which is inside of DrawerLayout, the problem is, everytime that I try to set a text I got a NullException, maybe the problem is because I'm not checking if it is open. I'm not doing nothing out of the ordinary...

```
private TextView my_textView;

onCreate.....

Drawer class...

my_textView = (Textview)findViewByid(R.id.nav_text);
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is it in a `NavigationView` header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the text is inside the `NavigationView` header.

First, Initialize your `NavigationView` header

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Next, Initialize the view inside the header.

```
TextView my_textView = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_text);
```

Now, Change the text by using `setText` method

```
my_textView.setText("New Text");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call drawerLayout.findViewByid() instead of findViewByid(). Because the textview is available in the drawerLayout. So change your code as below

```
private TextView my_textView;

onCreate.....

Drawer class...

my_textView = (Textview)drawerLayout.findViewByid(R.id.nav_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below if you want to access header views :

```
  View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);

        TextView tvUserName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.admin_header_name_tv);
```